In cosmology, how to calculate redshift from position and velocity?
As part of a computation in the context of Cosmology, I have the position and velocity of a galaxy in Cartesian coordinates, and I would like to find out its total redshift. In order to do this there seem to be several formulas that could be useful, but I am unsure of which one is the applicable one in this context.
One option would be to use $z=v/c$, where $v$ is the modulus of the velocity vector and $c$ is the speed of light, but as far as I know, this is an approximation.
Then we have the relativistic Doppler effect formula, where $v_{rad}$ is the radial velocity, but I suspect that the redshift we calculate using that expression is not the total redshift:
$$1+z=\sqrt{\dfrac{1+v_{rad}/c}{1-v_{rad}/c}}$$
Any suggestions? Thank you very much in advance!

The relativistic Doppler formula gives the same as the other formula when $v_{\mathrm{rad}}\ll c$,as
$$z=\sqrt{\frac{(1+v_{\mathrm{rad}}/c)}{(1-v_{\mathrm{rad}}/c)}}-1=\left[1+v_{\mathrm{rad}}/c+\frac12(v_{\mathrm{rad}}/c)^2+\cdots\right]-1\approx v_{\mathrm{rad}}/c$$
